# What's "allocation point" in Yield Farming?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, liquidity-provider, staking

In Sushiswap and, perhaps, Uniswap, as well as in the number of others DEX-es inherited from those, in **Yield Farming** there's the notion of "allocation point". What's it for? How does it work?

Comment: Do you mean the % of emissions that might be going to particular pair / pool out of the total emissions?

Comment: @Meet I mean whatever my question does.